# Concatenate ID field to filename

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access, I want to rename filename of the attachment with ID and filename so that there should be any problem for duplicates. For example, if the id is 1 and filename is ABC then name in the folder should be 1ABC or 1_ABC anything is fine. Currently it is saving as ABC.extension (pdf/docx/txt).

Comment: What are the values of the variables on that line when you get the error?

Comment: In MS Access table, the ID is field which contains values from 1 to 178 first row is 1, second row is 2. I want to take ID value from ID field and concatenate it to filename while save the attachment. In Dubug, it is asking me to assign value ID =1. But I want to take the program to pick up the value from table field.

Comment: You have no `rsB` ... your code can't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim counter As Long
    counter = SaveAttachments("D:\Test1")

    MsgBox counter & " files exported."

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function SaveAttachments(savePath As String, Optional strPattern As String = "*.*") As Long

    Dim r As DAO.Recordset
    Dim r2 As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim counter As Long
    
    Set r = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("Notices")

    Do While Not r.EOF

        Set r2 = r("Attachments").Value

        Do While Not r2.EOF

            If r2("FileName") Like strPattern Then
                strFullPath = savePath & "\" & r("ID") & "_" & r2("FileName")

                If Dir(strFullPath) = "" Then
                    r2("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            End If

            r2.MoveNext
        Loop

        If Not r2 Is Nothing Then r2.Close
        r.MoveNext
    Loop

    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Close

    SaveAttachments = counter
End Function
```